# SharePoint Online - Content type and required field issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, content-type-hub, provisioning, sharepoint-fields

I'm quite desperate so let me reproduce my issue on SharePoint Online.

I'm using **Content Type Hub** and I've published all content types to site collections (around 30 of them). Most of them work just fine but few content types have specific issue.

First, those problematic ones all inherit from parent Item and after publishing them to SC they don't inherit description of CT that I made on hub.

Secondly, I've set that all fields are optional on hub and they work as aspected on site collections also. But, when I try to make a wsp out of that specific content type (using Item as parent) fields change to required. I checked .cab file, due to [MSDN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-use-site-templates-60371B0F-00E0-4C49-A844-34759EBDD989?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) recommendation but it also shows that fields are not required. Example of one field:

```
<FieldRef ID="{e23d77f9-0320-4f69-9c59-4a92e62d1948}" Name="ServerType" Required="FALSE" Hidden="FALSE" AllowDeletion="TRUE" ReadOnly="FALSE" PITarget="" PrimaryPITarget="" PIAttribute="" PrimaryPIAttribute="" Aggregation="" Node="" />
```

I tried this on different site collections, made list template out of that content type (it worked fine and fields were optional but when I made site template out of it, it changes fields to required), recreated content types on hub, published content type Item to SCs, changed fields to optional in solution and packed it again but the same issue was there.

Please, any advice?
If I can give you any further info, ask anything.

Thanks in advance.

Bests,
M